# Image is not stored after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

Image is not stored into Images folder after upload attempt. What's wrong with my code?

**Here is my code:**

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   if (fileupload1.HasFile)
   {
      string fileName = fileupload1.FileName.ToString();
      string uploadFolderPath = "~/Image/";

      string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadFolderPath);

      fileupload1.SaveAs(filePath + "\\" + fileName);

      img1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + "/" + fileupload1.FileName.ToString();
      lblimg_name.Text=  fileupload1.FileName.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the ASP.NET process have write access to the specified directory? Does the directory actually exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (fileupload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Image/") + fileName);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Jegadeesh there is no problem with saving image in OP code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<asp:FileUpload>`, try this:

Or Describe in detail

```
string strFileName = "fileName";
string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileupload1.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("folderpath" + strFileName + strFileType));
```

Comment: You tried this code described above?
Please verify folder exists ?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
img1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + "/" + fileupload1.FileName.ToString();
```

to

```
img1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" +  fileupload1.FileName;
```

you have additional `"/"`  in your path

Comment: this is correct and nothing wrong in code instead of what is mentioned here for saving image as it will save if there exist Image folder on root.

Comment: img1.ImageUrl = "~/Image" + "/" + fileupload1.FileName.ToString();
this tag is used to preview image..if i remove +"/"+ then image is not displayed..

Comment: now you have `"~/Image" ` but in your original post you have `"~/Image/"`, my answer valid for your original post

Comment: string strFileName = "fileName"; which filename?

Comment: `fileupload1.FileName`